# Wifi shows connected but webpages loads after a coffee break

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10

My wifi connection shows connected but the page loads very slow and sometimes it shows up this error.

[image]

These are some of the ways I tried to resolve this but none worked so far.

1. Clear browser cache and delete history completely.
2. Restart machine twice or thrice and shutdown.
3. Disconnect wifi and reconnect wifi by entering the network security key again.
4. Tried executing all the following commands in sequence and restarted the machine.

   - ipconfig /release
   - ipconfig /all
   - ipconfig /flushdns
   - ipconfig /renew
   - netsh int ip set dns
   - netsh winsock reset
5. Changed the Internet protocol Version 4(TCP/IPV4) Properties
   as obtain an IP address automatically and Use the following DNS Server addresses.
   Preferred DNS server : 8.8.8.8
   Alternate DNS server : 8.8.4.4

But, when I connect to my wifi at home(TP Link router) it works like charm, without doing any of the above tweaks. And, I can connect to same wifi from my mobile without any disruption.

Here are some details.

- Windows 10
- Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter
- Router : Netgear genie

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that this is strictly a WIFI issue. Try moving around, and see if you can get pages to load faster. WIFI degrades with distance, and interfering WIFI channels (e.g. Other WIFI networks on the same or similar frequencies) can make your connection act like this too.

If you can get pages to load faster (while you're closer to the WIFI hotspot) then one of these is definitely your problem.

If this is a work network, contact your IT department, and let them know your symptoms and what you suspect.

If moving around doesn't solve the problem, try using other devices on the same WIFI that is causing you problems. (Try using your phone perhaps. Make sure you're not getting connectivity through your data and mistaking it for WIFI connectivity. You could also try another person's laptop.) If those devices don't have any connection issues, it may still be an problem with your wireless card, even though it works on your home WIFI. Try using a USB WIFI card in this case and see if your problem fixes itself with that.

If the other devices do have issues, then it's likely a problem with the hotspot itself, and that will need to be troubleshooted separately. (Turning a hotspot off and on again despite the cliché actually can resolve many of these types of problems if it's the cause)

Hope this helps!